# How to get top position of TImage picture?

Tags: delphi, timage

I have a TImage with `Align := alClient`, `Stretch := True`, `Proportional := True` and `Center := True` inside a TPanel. How to get the top pixel position of the picture that is drawn in the image?

Perhaps an image describing the problem will help:
[image]

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262023/1992767), but could not get the answer for what I need which is closely related.

Comment: Obviously you have `Center := true` as well.

Comment: Edited question accordingly

Comment: `Center := True` saved my life, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will only be space left at the top and bottom if the aspect ratio of the image is greater than that of the panel. Assuming this is the case, the desired distance is

```
round(Panel.Height - (Panel.Width / Image.Picture.Width) * Image.Picture.Height) / 2);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect.